How to export custom metrics from apache beam to Flink dashboard?
I'm creating a beam pipeline to run on flink runner. I've created
custom metrics in beam(JAVA SDK). But I'm unable to see it in flink
dashboard or flink rest API response or prometheus. FLink job is also not in dettached mode.
Although I'm able to see under Accumulators section but not under metrics. Under accumulators I can see,
{ "metrics": { "attempted": [{ "urn": "beam:metric:user:sum_int64:v1", "type": "beam:metrics:sum_int64:v1", "payload": "FA==", "labels": { "NAMESPACE": "Bingo", "NAME": "bingotest", "PTRANSFORM": "log/ParMultiDo(LogOutput)" } }] } }
I'm also able to log the metrics in beam part.
I'm using Apache Beam 2.55.0 and Flink runner 1.16.
Please let me know if this is the correct way to do this or am I missing
something?
